# Redirecting after login in django rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to redirect to a particular url after the user logs in. I am using django rest framework's built-in user authentication. I have tried the following code:

In urls.py, I have the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^register/$',views.CreateUserView.as_view(),name='user'),
    url(r'^api-auth/',include('rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^',include(router.urls)),
]
```

In settings.py, I have included the following:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/task'
```

I am on the following page 'localhost/register' and after creating a user and logging in, it redirects to same 'localhost/register page'. How do I redirect to the homepage? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Do you write any view for login?

Comment: I am just using the built in login view of the django framework. Have not built any custom view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this login view

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

def Login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    #AuthenticationForm_can_also_be_used__

    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        form = login(request,user)
        messages.success(request, f' wecome {username} !!')
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        messages.info(request, f'account done not exit plz sign in')
form = AuthenticationForm()
return render(request, 'user/login.html', {'form':form,'title':'log in'})
```

add this to views.py
and set any redirect this is a part of my project in case you need to see full file [link](https://github.com/itsvinayak/iert_django_webapp/blob/master/user/views.py)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will definitely try it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `views.py` after registration you should `redirect` to `login` page or your `home` page.

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            # REDIRECT here
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Also you can use redirection like this:

`<your_app>/urls.py`

```py
from . import views

app_name = 'your_app_name'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

in your `settings.py` add `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '<your_app_name>:index'`